# click the forgot link email field should be validate using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**click the forgot link email field should be validate using javascript,i have a done code any mistake please suggest me,below shown javascript code link may be conflict go through once and suggest me**

```
<form  id="form1" name="form1"   action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
  </div>
  <!--<div id='errorDiv' class='col-xs-12 pull-right'> </div>-->
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  
  </div>
  <!--<div id='errorDivv' class='col-xs-12 pull-right'> </div>-->
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" value="ulogin" >Login</button>
    <?php
      if (isset($message)) {
        echo $message;
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="field-wrap">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/testing.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<!-- Did you omit follow library? -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
      rules: {
        email: "required"
      },
      messages: {
        email: "Please specify your name"
      }
    }) 
    $('#btn-show-forgot').on('click', function() {
      $("#form1").valid();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
              email: "required"
            },
            messages: {
              email: "Please specify your name"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
              form.submit();
            }
          });//validate()
        });
      </script>
```

`submitHandler` is called when the form is validated successfully. So, here we are submitting the form once it has validated successfully.

Comment: problem is forgot link is not even working,may be so many javascript link which are all usefull suggest me